# RoR - JQuery Datatables Pagination Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatable, pagination

I have added [jquery-datatables-rails](https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails) gem to my Rails 4 application. It is correctly showing features included in the plugin BUT the pagination is always showing up first single page number [1](https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails) which shows first 50 records always.

Please correct me where I am doing any mistake, so that I may see:

`Index` function in my **models_controller.rb** always returns **50** records:

```
def index
  if params[:q].blank?
    @search = Model.search()
    @models = @search.result.page params[:page]
  else
    @search = Model.search(params[:q])
    @models = @search.result.page params[:page]
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render :json => @models, :except => [:created_at, :updated_at] }
  end
end

def search
  render :index
end
```

`Javascript` initializes the **DataTables**:

```
table = $('.table-models').DataTable({
  iDisplayLength: 50
});
```

I suspect that my error lies inside the **models_controller** but I am unable to figure out exactly. Please assist...

Comment: Are you sure that DataTable use correct param names (page, q, etc). Is autoload path correct? Check that you enable server-side processing: $('#example').dataTable( {
  "serverSide": true,
  "ajax": "your_path"
} );

Comment: @SergeySokolov I am new to RoR and jQuery world, so been unable to understand: **1)** DataTable does not seem to use params (page, q, etc.). How can I do that? **2)** What is autoload path ? **3)** What should "ajax: your_path" look like in Rails ?

Comment: 1. To load new page for your table you need to get new records from server (if "serverSide": true), DataTables need page param to know what page return to datatable from server. 2. Path for controller's action to load records. 3. your_path - it is path for your controller's action to load records with pagination (index in your sample). I advise you to look on https://github.com/antillas21/ajax-datatables-rails